# Commutative monoids $(S,+,0)$ where $\forall x,y \in S$ $x+ y = x$ implies $y = 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, definition, monoid

> Is there a definition/name for such monoids?
>
> Has any theory been developed for such monoids?
>
> Are there any any references/links delving into this with perhaps additional axioms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One algebraic structure which might fit the bill is that of a cancellative monoid. This is a special case of a cancellative semigroup:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellative_semigroup. In particular, if $(S,+,0)$ is our monoid, we have the cancellative law: for all $x,y,z\in S$,
$$ x+y=x+z \implies y=z$$ The property $x+y=x$ implies $y=0$ is a consequence of this. I am personally unaware of a monoid with *just* the property $x+y=x$ implies $y=0$.

Comment: Yes. You need a couple of axioms to get anything going here! But now I can unabashedly say 'given a cancellative monoid'!

Comment: Also can say: A cancellative [positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zerosumfree_monoid) monoid $(M,0,+)$.